Positioning array content to align with labels in itemize environment
I am trying to align an array under an enumerate label, and it looks like the first image, how to make it look like the second one
 
I am also including the code I am using. Thanks for your responses.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
    \item 
        $
        \begin{array}{c|c|c}
        A & B & C \\
        \hline
        \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} \\
        \text{x} & \text{y} & \text{z} \\
        \end{array}  
        $
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


Set the anchor point for the array to [t]op:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
  \item 
    $\begin{array}[t]{ c | c | c }
            A    &     B    &     C    \\
        \hline
        \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} \\
        \text{x} & \text{y} & \text{z}
      \end{array}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

